# Combining logs from a cluster architecture

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, redhat

I've been looking for solutions to combine logs from a load balanced architecture so that I could effectively debug a server error or an access log. As of now I need to check each web node individually. Any out of the box solutions would be nice.

Comment: I think you're looking for a service like Loggly (https://www.loggly.com/docs/nginx-server-logs/) which would collect all your logs in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many OOTB tools -- commercial and FOSS -- that will collect
your logs and give an interface to visualize and search them.  For
FOSS, have a look at
[logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) and
[fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/), which you can self-host (if
you're not ready to off-site your logging).

You've thus far probably been grepping a log file on each server.  A
simple improvement to this is a little script that does it in parallel
across machines.  I occasionally do this with a "telegrep" script that
is called like:

```
% TG_REMOTES=app1:app2:app3
% telegrep somepattern /path/to/monster.log.gz
```

The script essentially passes the pattern and file to ssh to loop over
all the `TG_REMOTES`, like:

```
for svr in TG_REMOTES; do ssh $svr "zgrep --some-options... $pattern $logfile"; done
```